# Javascript getters/setters for all properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can set a getter like this..

```
var o = { get test(){return 'ya'}}
o.test
 ==> "ya"
```

So can I set one that is global to all properties and future-created properties?

```
var o = { get _(){return 'ya'}}
o.test = '1';
o.test
 ==> "ya"
o.moretest = '2';
o.moretest
 ==> "ya"
```

Comment: Not without using proxies from `--harmony` flag

Comment: We all wish we could already do this. You can manually define getters and setters for properties after an object has already been created, though.

Answer (score 1):

Making some lightweight type checking on POJOs..  Anyway, this worked for me..

```
$ node --harmony

require('harmony-reflect');

function prox(target) {
  return Proxy(target, {
    get: function(target, name) {
      if(name in target) return target[name];
      throw Error('Not a valid property');
    },
    set: function(target, name, val) {
      if(name in target) return target[name] = val;
      throw Error('Not a valid property');
    }
  });
}

var o = prox({name:'john'});
console.log(o.name);
o.name = 'jo';
console.log(o.name);

o.age = 21;
>> error...
```

Comment: You can achieve exactly this functionality with `Object.seal`

Comment: +1 for `Object.seal`. I recommend posting that as an answer as I think that's exactly what he's looking for.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  I'll have to decide if I want to throw errors when someone attempts to add a prop, which I don't believe I get w/Object.seal, but at least I can use that without --harmony.  The goal is to basically make an object always conform to a model, without all the model frameworks and such.  thx,